How to produce a smooth trajectory?
I have some viewpoints with transpose and rotate matrix.
e.g.
R = ([[-0.97888774, -0.03123735, -0.20199756],
[0.08031109, 0.84999346, -0.52063542],
[0.18795988, -0.52586628, -0.82953948]])
T = ([0.25886811, 0.18360791, 3.27496091])
I have some of these matrix, how could I get the smooth trajectory.
I consider that I could use b-spline on transpose matrix, but it could not directly use on rotate matrix, how should I do with rotate matrix.

You can use the Euler axis and angle (rotation-vector) representation for the 3D rotation. Convert the rotation matrix to the rotation-vector representation (see for example here for a formula), perform the interpolation on the rotation-vector and convert the results back to matrix representation using the Euler–Rodrigues formula.
Another option can be to us quaternions (see here for example).

Thank you very much. I tried using quaternions for interpolation and successfully it works!

You're most welcome, happy it helped, I'd appreciate if you upvote + accept
